# jenkins-pipeline load scoping "method code too large"

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a pretty complex pipeline to handle legacy builds.
There are currently 8 stages, and more on the way - perhaps total of 12-15 stages.

Each stage does pretty similar actions:
 - take a list, and for each item
 - create entry in map that
 - allocates a node, and executes a set of BAT scripts (yes, windows)
and then run list in parallel

The current pipeline is about 1,000 lines long, and I'm getting the "method too large" error

I'm in process of refactoring this DSL into separate load-able scripts.

So far, so good.
But I just ran a test that indicates loading a script is additive to the overall pipeline.  So I'd like to learn what is best to do here.

**Test:**

***base.groovy:***

```
def myVar      //wchi is global (to basRef, i thought)
def setTest() { myVar='abc' }
def getTest() { return myVar }
```

***pipeline.groovy***

```
stage('one') {
     def basRef = load('base.groovy')
     basRef.setTest()
     echo basRef.getTest()
}

stage('two') {
     def basRef = load('base.groovy')
     echo basRef.getTest()
}
```

stage one shows "abc" as expected.
stage two ALSO SHOWS "abc"

**My ask:**

How do I know using `loadable` files will not result in "method too large"?

What is the scope of a loadable file?

I've tried setting `basRef = null` to allow garbage collection to work, but I'm not sure it does.

Thanks for any guidance on this.